# Continuous variable for graph of boiling point of different chain lengths

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, molecular-structure

Looking at the boiling points of alkanes (for examples), many graphs plot boiling point against chain length :

[image]

However, there is an issue with the line of best fit- since chain length is a discrete variable (the line of best fit suggests you can have non-integer carbon chains). What is a more suitable alternative ?

[image]

I have seen examples which use wiener indices (not familiar with these), but it appears the indices should be integer values.

Relative formula mass is another possible alternative (since there could be decimal Mr from isotopes).  However, is there a more suitable alternative ?

Comment: 1. It's fine to have a fit equation where some of the values in the domain (nonintegers in this case) are invalid. 2. Your plot doesn't look like a fit line, it looks like it simply connects each data point with a straight line.

Comment: I think there is more than simple statistics treatment. I am even not sure that a fit should be there. In so saying, I assume the BP of alkanes as data with basically no fluctuation. But I know it depends on the context as well as that you just gave an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I refer to a good response on the general question ["Discrete variables in regression model?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52146/discrete-variables-in-regression-model) found on a sister site.

The quote in part:

> General confusion appears when you mix in ordinal data, such as those 5-point "how satisfied are you?" questions. They are expressed in whole number, very easily to be confused with discrete data. However, each jump in the scale does not necessarily mean the same thing. E.g. a jump from "4: happy" to "5: very happy" is not necessarily the same as a jump from "1: very unhappy" to "2: unhappy." In that case, the variable should not be put into the regression as is, but treated differently (search "dummy variable in regression" to learn more.)

Now, in the current context of chain length as the explanatory variable per a standard regression analysis, one could argue for a solution composed of a **mixture** with known varying chain lengths, a standard regression analysis could still present meaningful information in such a heterogeneous composition.

However, with respect to a homogeneous single chemical composition, I believe a more difficult argument to make in general. So, do consider a dummy variable approach especially with a large number of data points. Be mindful, however, of the impact of a loss in degrees of freedom (from employing an explanatory 'dummy' variable for each chain length). This expanded regression model generally results in higher expected errors on parameter estimates and also wider associated confidence intervals as well.

You may also want to consider weighing (inversely by the ascribed regression variance estimate for each model) the fitted value especially when working with smaller data sets and extended chain lengths.